# Play audio stream with Audio API

Tags: html, audio, audio-streaming

I am working with the HTML5 audio api to play sound. This works fine with regular mp3 files but when using a sound stream such as `http://95.173.167.24:8009`, it fails to play.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
 if('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
    var myAudioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
    }

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://95.173.167.24:8009', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.addEventListener('load', bufferSound, false);
    request.send();


    function bufferSound(event) {
      var request = event.target;
      var source = myAudioContext.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = myAudioContext.createBuffer(request.response, false);
      source.connect(myAudioContext.destination);
      source.noteOn(0);
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The problem likely isn't in your code, but the fact that SHOUTcast servers provide broken HTTP responses.  Most browsers ignore it, but some do not.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, Ok I'm using the latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that SHOUTcast is detecting your User-Agent string as a browser.  It looks for any string with `Mozilla` in it, and says "Oh, that's a browser!  Send them the admin panel."

You need to force the usage of the audio stream.  Fortunately, this is easily done by adding a semicolon at the end of your URL:

```
http://95.173.167.24:8009/;
```

Note that the User-Agent string in your logs will be `MPEG OVERRIDE`.

This will work for most browsers.  Some browsers may still not like the HTTP-like resopnses that come from SHOUTcast, but this will at least get you started.

Comment: On another note, if you can't get this working the way you want, and would like a proper HTTP stream, I have a service available for testing right now.  http://www.audiopump.co/preview.php